# Symfony2 – Is there a standard for the name of entity var inside a controller & view?

Tags: symfony

I'm curious if there's a standard/recommended practice for the name of the variable storing the entity in a controller action or view.

```
public function demoAction(User $entity)
{
    return $this->render('...', [
        'entity' => $entity,
    ]);
}
```

I've seen some places where it's done this way (always name the main entity var `$entity`) and other's where `$entity` is `$user` (for example).

In my opinion, using `$entity` everywhere get's confusing when there are 2 entities and then you either have one called "entity" and the other something else.

Is there a standard/recommended practice? For Symfony? Or maybe something for the wider PHP world? Or for an ORM, ie, Doctrine?

Comment: The entity (or anything other) variables can be named whatever you want them to be but for readability sake it makes sense to name them what they are rather than anything generic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, call them what they are, like `$user`, `$userProfile` ...

The `$entity` is from autogenerated stuff Symfony creates. Maybe this behavior could be optimized in Symfony3, so that the generated variable names are derived from the concrete class name.

Comment: You can also override the CRUD generator skeletons to do something like you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the methods naming conventions (e.g. `yourmethodAction` in controllers which the routing process depends on), you can name your variables using your own appreciation.

Of course, as in all other programming languages and frameworks, choose logical and comprehensible names.

For entities, I generally use the name of the entity, in camelcase.

i.e. For an entity named `ProductCategory`, you can use `$productCategory`

See the [Symfony coding standards](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html) for more informations.